# PostgreSQL: how to take query results and change them on the fly before saving to file

Tags: string, postgresql, replace, output

I want to know how to take query results and change them in to human talk.

For example:

```
Select backup_set.id, backup_set.status, backup_set.type 
from backset.table
```

Then take the backup_set.type result, which is usually a number such as 1,2,3,4,5 and change it to something like SUSPENDED, SCHEDULED etc...  But I dont want to change the data in the table just the output.

Comment: Please post your up to now attempts and results, so we can give further advise.

Comment: Search for `case` and `foreign keys`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a `CASE` statement.

```
Select backup_set.id, backup_set.status, 
       case backup_set.type 
          when 1 then 'SUSPENDED'
          when 2 then 'SCHEDULED'
          else 'UNKNOWN'
       end as "type"
from backset.table
```

But it would be better if you stored that information in another table and make the `type` column a foreign key to that lookup table. Then you can use a simple join to retrieve the description.

**Edit**

If you want to replace `UNKNOWN` with the actual numeric value, you just need to put that into the `ELSE` part. You need to cast the number to a text value though:

```
Select backup_set.id, backup_set.status, 
       case backup_set.type 
          when 1 then 'SUSPENDED'
          when 2 then 'SCHEDULED'
          else backup_set.type::text
       end as "type"
from backset.table
```

Comment: What happens if I want to leave the status column as is for numbers like 3,4,5,6 etc?

Comment: @BoricuaTec sorry I don't understand your question. The status column is unchanged in the above query

Comment: in the results that are returned now the ones that are suspended and scheduled enumarated as such but now the ones that are not caught CASE are labeled as UNKNOWN.  Is there a way to pass the value through?